# Is there a simple way in ASP.NET MVC to do a INSERT query to an external MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'd like to do just 1 insert query to an external MySQL database in my controller. I don't want to add the database to my project or work with Entity.

Is there a simple way to do the insert query on the external MySQL server?

Edit: I'm using .NET Core 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ADO.NET. Just create a connection to MySQL database and do the query you need. 
See example here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-with-asp-net-core-mvc-web-app-using-ado-net/

Comment: I don't think this is MySQL though. How can I use MySqlConnection() instead of SqlConnection() ? Edit: Installing MySql.Data with NuGet fixed it.